# Postgres Data Encryption Using LUKS with dm-crypt

Tags: linux, postgresql, encryption, luks

We have encrypted volume using LUKS.

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /root/test1 volume1
```

and mounted on

```
mount /dev/mapper/volume1 /mnt/files
```

We created postgres data directory inside /mnt/files and able to start the postgres database.

```
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_ctl -D /mnt/files/postgres/ -l /var/logs/postgres/postgrs.log  start
```

Even though we unmounted /mnt/files

```
sudo umount -l /mnt/files
```

When we try to close volume using LUKS.

```
sudo cryptsetup luksClose volume1
```

Getting following errors:

> device-mapper: remove ioctl on volume1 failed: Device or resource busy

Comment: So you had a running PostgreSQL on a volume you unmounted? While PostgreSQL can do a recovery on next restart, it's still a bit audacious –
 and certainly not a good practice on a business environment.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you didn't shut down PostgreSQL before unmounting.

As long as a PostgreSQL process is running, it will have filehandles open.  You need to kill them all.

Oh, and BTW, you may have just corrupted your database.